# How can I make Chrome open bookmarked pages in new tab by default?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks, tabs

Current situation:

I am currently browsing a page (say, www.google.com). I want to open a bookmarked page (say, www.bing.com), but I want to keep the current page (Google) opened. I need to click on new tab, then click on the bookmark for Bing. Alternatively, I can right click and open Bing in new tab.

But I want none of those because why click twice when one is enough?

---

What I want:

I am currently on Google. I want to open Bing, so I click on the bookmark and Bing opens in a new tab. Google remains open.

---

I am aware of a duplicate question linked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/201101/chrome-bookmarks-to-default-in-new-tab). However it didn't really provide a satisfactory answer. Changing every link to javascript breaks the icon and is a pain to do; middle clicking doesn't really work because I'm on a laptop and the touchpad does not support middle clicking.
I hope there is an extension for Chrome that can redefine this behavior to the way I want. A hidden setting in Chrome would be even better but I doubt Chrome offers that.

Comment: I have just transitioned from Firefox to Chrome, and I am puzzled that such basic functionality doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively, you could use

```
javascript:window.open('url')
```

For example,

```
javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com')
```

[image: Javascript bookmark]

Comment: Just to clarify why I'm not accepting this answer: this method works, but is clumsy and breaks the favicon. Some might argue otherwise, but I think having a working favicon contributes greatly to usability.

Comment: @cyqsimon Yes. But I think this is the accepted answer till something better comes up. Then you change accepted answer when that happens.

Comment: +1 because it's clever and gets it done in the only way currently available. I'm suggesting to move the OP's stated caveats to the answer, for better visibility.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is old, but I hope it's ok if I revive the thread.  Whether it's on my laptop/desktop, I keep finding myself clicking on my bookmarks and losing everything in my existing tab.  No more.

I have created a chrome extension that changes all existing bookmarks and also newly created ones to open on a left click.  It's already saved me quite a few headaches.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-bookmarks/haandfikjmhahlpkhapifhkanmdaakop

I understand that the favicons are now default, but I have not found a fix for this yet. Chrome makes that part a little difficult. 
I hope this extension helps anyone and everyone.  Thanks!

Comment: Wow, never expected someone would actually go and write a dedicated plugin for this... One question: is there a 'revert' function for this plugin, so I can undo the bookmark modification in one click?

Comment: There isn't a revert function, but I think it might be easy to add.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Scary, I don't dare to install this.

Answer (score 6):

I don't really follow on the bookmark thing you're talking about, but if you're looking for the similar function of clicking the middle wheel, then Ctrl+left click on a link. This will open the link in a new tab while keeping the page you're on active.

There are many keyboard shortcuts for Chrome and it's worth taking a look at their support site under keyboard and mouse shortcuts for a full list.

Another one you might like is ctrl+shift+left click which will open the link in a new tab and jump you to it.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Comment: Also right-click and "Open in new tab".

Comment: It's simply a matter of personal preference. I want the default action of clicking on a bookmark to be "open in new tab" instead of "open in current tab". All of the methods you mentioned would work, but they either require more than one click or both hands to perform, and I see that as an inconvenience. Analogously, in Windows you can change the default action of double clicking a folder to be "open in new window". I wish for a similar functionality for Chrome tabs, either by modifying some settings in stock Chrome, or by installing extensions.

Comment: This is far and away the best, least hacky, most secure, least inconvenient answer and should be the accepted answer, at least until the option exists in Chrome settings. It solves the OP's issue since they said nothing about using both hands, like in the previous comment. Holding the Ctrl key is hardly an inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

For windows users, you can use AutoHotKey to achieve what your need.

How : when you click left mouse, ahk can intercept the mouse down event, then use some magic logic to determine whether to replace simple click with **ctrl+shift+click** , which will open bookmark url in new tab, foreground.

And with the bookmark name fetched (ahk can get text under mouse via accessibility api), plus current window class and size plus mouse position,  you can better  determine whether it is suitable to send ctrl+shift+click.

here is the example script :

Where acc_lite.ahk is helper library for getting text under mouse.

And new_tab_bookmark.ahk contains our magic logic!

[Chrome open bookmarked pages in new tab by default. (single left click open new tab in foreground )](https://gist.github.com/KnIfER/1c968deb61a6eb893842a286a7d12524)

Answer (score -1):

I use the [New Tab Redirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna?hl=en) extension.