# Start an internal chrome page using a Windows batch file

Tags: batch, batch-file

I am trying to open an internal chrome page from a Windows Batch file, the following works for an external site:

```
@echo off

start chrome https://google.co.uk/
```

However the following only opens an empty Chrome tab:

```
@echo off

start chrome "chrome://bookmarks/"
```

The following also does not work:

```
@echo off

start chrome "chrome://settings/"
```

I've tried researching this issue and can't find a solution anywhere online.

Comment: What is //bookmarks exactly?  What are you actually trying to do?  If you aren't hosting a web server, do you want a directory opened?  Try (just for fun) `start chrome file///c:/` and you will see the root of your c drive.  Otherwise, you have two options.. you can open a specific HTML document on your drive (the file:/// syntax will work here too) or you can open a path on the drive.  [I don't think that Chrome has the feature to open a tab of your bookmarks](https://superuser.com/questions/201101/chrome-bookmarks-to-default-in-new-tab) although many have asked for it.  I think Firefox can.

Comment: You could write your own simple HTML page with your bookmarks in it and call that using the syntax above or have a folder of URL links and call that using the syntax above.   Hopefully someone has a better suggestion than I.

Comment: Hi, I am basically trying to open any internal chrome pages starting with "chrome://" using a batch file

Comment: I don't think that this is possible with chrome. I just looked at every command line supported [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) and see nothing that can help us.  I see it done with AppleScript so I can only assume that something like PowerShell can do it.  Hopefully, someone who knows more than me will come along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this [bat file start open chrome chrome://downloads/](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325297/3080770) Not Possible !

---

But here is a little hack for this but in `vbscript` using `SendKeys`

---

```vbs
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "chrome.exe",1,False
WScript.Sleep 7000
WshShell.SendKeys("chrome://settings")
WshShell.SendKeys("{enter}")
```

---

Or in `Powershell` too like this example :

```Powershell
$shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$shell.Run("chrome",1,"False")
$id = Get-Process -Name chrome | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id -First 1
Start-Sleep -s 7
$shell.AppActivate($id)
$shell.SendKeys("chrome://settings/")
$shell.SendKeys("{enter}")
```

Comment: Yep, this is the best workaround I've found so far, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using the `start` command the **first** set of quotes are the console window title.

Either don't use quotes (your parameter has no spaces so quotes aren't required) or specify the window title.

```
start "Title" chrome "https://google.co.uk/"
```